# Making axios to call api in useeffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch an api using axios and set it in a state in my App.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import UserDetails from "./user/userDetails";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState([]);

  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
     return await 
      axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api").then((response) => {
        if (response.data.results) {
          setUserDetails(response.data.results);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  getUser();
  console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", userDetails);

  return <>{<UserDetails data={userDetails} />}</>;
}

export default App;
```

i am able to get the response from getUser function but was not able to set in in userDetails what is wrong in this implementation

Comment: Put `getUser();` inside the useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the getUser function inside useEffect

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import axios from "axios";
import UserDetails from './user/userDetails';

function App() {

 const [userDetails,setUserDetails]=useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
  getUser();
 },[])

 const getUser=async()=>{
  try {
   return await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api').then(response => {
    if(response.data.results){
     setUserDetails(response.data.results);
    }
   });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR',error);
  }
 }

 return <UserDetails data={userDetails}/>
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to call this function getUser(); in the use effect that time is working

Answer (score 0):

Moved the `getUser` function inside the `useEffect` hook and called it using `fetchUserDetails` function. Also updated the `setUserDetails` function with the actual data from the response.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserDetails from './user/userDetails';

function App() {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api');
        const data = response.data.results;
        setUserDetails(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchUserDetails();
  }, []);

  console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', userDetails);

  return (
    <>
      <UserDetails data={userDetails} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```